# Affine transformation (shear) opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

So I have an image which I want to apply a shear transformation on using OpenCV.

Here's a function I wrote,

```
Mat shearMat(Mat img){

Mat temp;
img.copyTo(temp);
Mat M(2,3,CV_32F);


M.at<uint16_t>(0,0) = 1;
M.at<uint16_t>(0,1) = 0;
M.at<uint16_t>(0,2) = 0;

M.at<uint16_t>(1,0) = 0;
M.at<uint16_t>(1,1) = 1;
M.at<uint16_t>(1,2) = 0;

warpAffine(temp, temp, M , Size(temp.cols,temp.rows));
imshow("Sheared_Image", temp);
```

M is the inputArray for  `warpAffine(<#InputArray src#>, <#OutputArray dst#>, <#InputArray M#>, <#Size dsize#>);`

I need to know how M should look like if I want to apply a shear transformation. It says it should be a 2x3 Matrix. When I try to show the image now, nothing appears. I know that `M.at<uint16_t>(1,0)` should be the shear factor, but its not working with warpAffine.

Thanks!

Comment: Surely you should access `CV_32F` as `M.at<float>(1,0) = 0.0f` (for example) not `uint16_t` - can you show the result you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong data type.

```
M.at<float>(0,0) = 1;
M.at<float>(0,1) = 0;
M.at<float>(0,2) = 0;

M.at<float>(1,0) = 0.5;
M.at<float>(1,1) = 1;
M.at<float>(1,2) = 0;
```